# Dynamic filters - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the below dataset:

[image]

I need to calculate the number of accounts grouped by the datedif between today and first date per an account when type = 'cash'.

If I find the min date per account and type 'cash' using

```
first date = 
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( tbl[date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( tbl, tbl[account] ),tbl[type]="cash")
```

, I get:

[image]

And then, applying datedif to find the difference between today() and first date, I get:

[image]

The requirement, however, is not to hard-code the type. However, if I use the below formula:

```
first date = 
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( tbl[date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( tbl, tbl[account] ))
```

and then, 'cash' as a filter, I get the below result which is incorrect:

[image]

Comment: what is your final expected output with cash and con-cash selected?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps..

1. Change [Account] data type to Text.
2. First Date = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[Date]), ALLEXCEPT('Table',
   'Table'[Account], 'Table'[Type]))